# how can I fix files that are not showing in my local website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a pokedex project with html css and javascript,when I try to open it with VSCODE it works fine,but when I try to open the html local file the broswer doesn't find 2 local files, it keeps saying that:

file:///C:/assets/js/poke-api.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
GET file:///C:/assets/js/main.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

the problem is that the files are working when I try to open in VSCODE.

https://github.com/joaogabriel1902/Pokedex-Challenge - in case someone likes to see the code.

I tried to uninstall some of the extensions that I have to see if would work.But nothing happened it keeps not finding the files.

Comment: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server-plus-plus

install this extension in vs code from extension tab in vs code. 

Then right click on index.html and click live preview

Comment: the reason error is coming is probably due to the fact that your are trying to run a website using file:// protocol, but it needs to run over http://localhost

Answer (score 1):

## I think the clue is in the error message

```
GET file:///C:/assets/js/poke-api.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 
GET file:///C:/assets/js/main.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

You should not want your browser to be looking at C:/assets, unless you actually want to use the root folder of your hard disk, as your project folder (since "assets" is in the project folder itself).

Something has gone wrong in how you are telling the browser how to start the project. I suggest trying these steps.

1. Use Google Chrome
2. Drag the ".html" file from your explorer window, into the Google Chrome window.

That should trigger Chrome to open the HTML file in the right way.

## How to access files in subfolders

Two ways seem to work for me:

```
<script src="./assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

When I try a third way, however, I get an error message just like yours:

```
<script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

[image]

## Attempt to fix

Your code does seem to be using one method that works on my system, so I am surprised that you are getting an error. However why don't you try the *other* method that works on my system, and see what happens?

Remove the `./` when accessing the Javascript files, by changing

```
<script src="./assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

to this

```
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

Please let me know how you get on, because I am curious too.

Answer (score 0):

Following way of code:

```
<script src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>
```